# Unable to use Model.findbyId in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, model-view-controller

I am using MongoDB along with nodejs, expressjs, ejs and passport. I have setup the MVC and am sending a dynamic URL from views.

This is my MongoDB schema:

```
const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    country: {
        type: String,
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    vaccine: {
        name: String,
        price: Number,
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

From views I have sent a URL which has this format /vaccine/{vaccine.name}, where vaccine.name is the data in the schema. On serverside i am slicing the URL to get the exact vaccine name. This is my query to get the user:

```
const Company = require("../models/company");

module.exports.transaction_req = function (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        const req_url = req.url.slice(1);
        // console.log(req_url);
        Company.findOne({vaccine.name: req_url}, function(err, user){
        return res.render('transaction');
        })

    }
    return res.redirect('/login');
};
```

It is giving this error saying that I cannot use '.' in query:

```
Company.findOne({vaccine.name: req_url}, function(err, user){
                                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

**What is the alternative to get user with that given `vaccine.name`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use property accessor in query, wrap your `vaccine.name` into quotes, as `'vaccine.name'`.

Comment: Yes i just found that error. But I am facing a new one now.
How do I render my transactions page without having this error?
`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: @KrushnalPatel you are using callback in your query call, that is an asynchronous operation. I recommend you to rewrite your handler to async funtion and your query to use promises (remove callback, and add `.exec()` call on query object).
You can also just put else clause and wrap `return res.redirect('/login');` with it.
This error is happening because your code already sends response with `return res.redirect('/login')`.